# Carla simulator dependent on Unreal engine? Any alternative open source real-time 3D creation platform are available?

Tags: 3d, unreal-engine4, carla

I am trying to run carla Simulator on Azure ubuntu 18.04 machine, but as per the document we need to create an account in GitHub and Unreal engine, and we need to link those two accounts. Whether carla is dependent on unreal engine? Do we need to buy licencing for unreal engine in order to complete carla simulator setup or do we have any other alternate real-time 3D creation platform?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, yes you need UE4.
https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_linux/#unreal-engine

[image: You can see this image]

Edit: Looks like UE4.24 only.

You don't need to buy UE4. UE4 open source and free to use. (restrictions apply)

You need to create Epic Games account. Link to your GitHub profile, for download UE4 Source Code.
Afterwards Download Source Code, and compile for Linux. That's all.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried as per your suggestion and created account in unreal engine. But when i am trying to clone the unreal engine repo as mentioned in "https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_linux/#unreal-engine", it is saying that this repository doesn't exist. I tried to verify manually whether this repository exists or not, but it is saying '404 not found'.

Comment: Thats is why you need to link your epic games account to github.
Repo is hidden.
Go to https://www.epicgames.com/account/connections and select accounts tab, and link your github. Afterward verify from e-mail.

Comment: Thanks Berk, I was able to clone the repository

Comment: Your welcome. GLHF with simulator.
Ahh... Don't forget to marks as solved if solved your problem.

Comment: After installing I am trying to run “./CarlaUE4.sh” but getting following error.

“WARNING: vallium/llvmpipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
vulkan: No DRI3 support detected - required for presentation
Note: you can probably enable DRI3 in your Xorg config”

Answer (score 0):

You can install Carla binaries without getting Unreal Engine or making an Epic account, see [Quick start installation](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start_quickstart/).

You only need Unreal Engine if you build the project from source, which is only necessary if you plan to modify the project or build for an unsupported platform.